# VBA userform Image1.picture change not working after a boolean enable/disable

Tags: excel, vba

I have found some strange behaviour which is really putting a crimp on an otherwise smooth looking excel app I've built.

I have 4 images:

Image1 is the main image, which has a mouse_move event on it.
Image2 is an invisible image on top of image1 which also has a mouse_move event.

Image3 and Image4 act as storage for two images which are placed in to image1 depending on which mouse_move event is fired.

The mouse_move events check first if a boolean "isLocked" is true, if so then they do not change the picture.

If I click on image2 to set "isLocked" to true, then the images don't swap. Cool! If I click on image2 again to set "isLocked" to false, then the program resumes as expected and the images swap as they should.

Now the problem, if I call the image2_click routine from anywhere else, the code resumes as expected but the images do not change from that point on.

I've reduced the code down as far as possible to replicate the behaviour and I hope someone can spot a fix/ error with my logic.

```
Dim isLocked As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Me.DrawBuffer = 1048576
isLocked = False
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_Click()
Call Image2_Click
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If Not isLocked Then
If Not Me.Image1.Picture = Me.Image3.Picture Then Me.Image1.Picture = Me.Image3.Picture
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
If Not isLocked Then
If Not Me.Image1.Picture = Me.Image4.Picture Then Me.Image1.Picture = Me.Image4.Picture
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Image2_Click()
If isLocked Then
    isLocked = False
Else
    isLocked = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: *"if I call the image2_click routine from anywhere else, the code resumes as expected but the images do not change from that point on"* The routine just flips the value of `isLocked`, Why do you expect it to do anything more?

Comment: Side comment. `Image2_Click` can simply be one line `isLocked = Not isLocked`

Comment: A.S.H - because when isLocked is false the pictures are supposed to change; going step by step through the code the pictures are apparently changing, the code is being processed, but the images on screen do not change. I've tried doevents, repaint, userform_initialize... I just don't get it. Also thanks Scott Holtzman for the elegant shortcut.